# Modify Date Cell in an Excel Workbook using JExcelApi in Java

Tags: java, jxl

I want to modify a date cell in excel. I even referred to http://www.andykhan.com but I didn't understand how to modify an already existing date cell. I want to modify in the same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Apache POI

http://poi.apache.org/

Plenty of documentation and forum help even in SO.

Comment: Sorry but I need JExcel only. I started this big project and I have to finish it in time. I cannot start from scratch and learn Apache POI. Is there any other way?